# Twitter Typeahead Highlighting

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am using [Twitter Typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js) ( the v0.10.5 *typeahead.bundle.js* [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.5/typeahead.bundle.js)) and [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) v4.0.6.

Everything is working as expected (I'm able to search my dataset and the autocomplete works) apart from the **highlighting** of words as I type. You can see an example of how this should appear [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#the-basics).

My code is below.

```
var books = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('title'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    prefetch: {
        url: 'books.json',
        ttl: 0,
        filter: function(list) {
            return $.map(list, function(book) {
                return {
                    title: book.title,
                };
            });
        }
    }
});

$('.demo .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: false,
    highlight: true, // <-- this doesn't work
    minLength: 1
}, {
    name: 'books',
    displayKey: 'title', 
    source: books.ttAdapter(),
    engine: Handlebars,
    templates: {
        empty: ['<div class="empty-message">', 'no results found', '</div>'].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>{{{title}}}</p>') 
    },
});
```

I don't think it's a css issue as I removed all of my css and there is still no highlighting.

I have tried the latest version of typeahead (v0.11.1) but this makes no difference.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you might need to add `.tt-cursor{
    color:#f1b218;
}` to your css? Give that a go

Comment: @TobyMellor actually that works! So simple and I've spent (wasted) so long, thank you! Add an answer ;)

Comment: No problem! I'll post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a lot of people are having the problem of not specifying the required parameter `minLength: x`.

In your case, you've already done this. The problem is that you need to add the following to CSS

```
.tt-cursor {
    color: #f1b218;
}
```